# Are there any good jQuery drag and drop file upload plugins?

Tags: jquery, css, html, drag-and-drop

Are there any good drag & drop jQuery plugins that give me the same functionality as dragging and dropping attachments in Gmail?

Preferably I would be able to see the upload progress as it is going.

But I don't want flash.

CSS, HTML5 and jQuery preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: This is specific to the browser you are using, and hence there is no crossBrowser jquery plugin for this. The browser has to allow to drop files into its window, without trying to load the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good jQuery Drag-and-drop file upload plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663741/is-there-a-good-jquery-drag-and-drop-file-upload-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed is an important thing to you, use this plugin, The API is very similar to jQuery UI's draggable and droppable plugins

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/event-delegated-drag-and-drop
some other links

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/01/15-jquery-plugins-giving-web-interfaces-drag-n-drop-capabilities.html

I have use this one for row drag and drop in table (grid), so check it out may be this will help u.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortunately, what I need is file upload drag & drop. i.e. dragging files from the desktop onto a designated 'drop zone' and having the files uploaded (like Gmail). Not dragging and dropping elements on the page like jQuery's Draggable and Droppable UI plugins.