# Can I use Jquery to implement a drag drop file from outside into web page (inter-Window drag drop) (like gmail attachment)?

Tags: file, drag-and-drop, window, external, html

Can I use Jquery to implement a drag drop file into web page (like gmail attachment)?

Research so far has not shown existing examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=drag+and+drop
- [jQuery Drag and Drop Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931257/jquery-drag-and-drop-upload) (yup, use Jquery, no sh**, sherlock, but HOW?)
- http://ask.metafilter.com/48575/Drag-and-drop-across-browser-windows (It's possible, but discussion here a bit vague
- [Are there any good jQuery drag and drop file upload plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487756/are-there-any-good-jquery-drag-and-drop-file-upload-plugins) (Question asks for gmail drag and drop, but answer is drag drop items *within* same browser page window, not from outside, from another window as in gmail)

Comment: Did you try the plugin listed from the 'jQuery Drag and Drop Upload' link?

Comment: +1 I'll have look: I think you mean http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dnd-file-upload from the 2nd comment in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931257/jquery-drag-and-drop-upload/4938029#4938029

Comment: I certainly do, [there's a how to on gcode](http://code.google.com/p/dnd-file-upload/wiki/howto)

Comment: +1 @Nicholas Smith - great. If it was an answer I would accept it unless there are better answers out there. (I don't think there are though).

Comment: @Nicholas Smith add your comments as an answer. Hopefully I will then be able to accept it.

Comment: I've added an answer on for you now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3900/discussion-between-nicholas-smith-and-rob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the plugin listed from the 'jQuery Drag and Drop Upload' link? If you do then there's a [how to](http://code.google.com/p/dnd-file-upload/wiki/howto) on gcode.

Comment: +1 Accepted :) Thanks @Nicholas Smith I wasn't available for chat. Wonder if there is an Android app for stack overflow chat - that would have been handy :)