# jQuery Drag and Drop Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I need to built a page that user can drag and drop file and upload it on ftp server. Its just an upload and nothing else. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: same as this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663741/is-there-a-good-jquery-drag-and-drop-file-upload-plugin

Comment: @Shrinath, those links are based on HTML5 and just working in certain browser. I need cross browser solution.

Comment: As @Dee said, try googling for JQuery plugins.. There are many...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drag n drop is a clientside issue, ASP runs on the server.

jquery is the correct approach for clientside coding problems.  jQuery is crossbrowser compatible

just google jQuery drag n drop upload for examples

Comment: @Thanks Dee. About ASP I meant using jQuery for interface, drag n drop, etc and using ASP for upload part. Do you think its possible? Do you have any example?

Comment: I ran the google search for you and immediatley found this:                                                                 http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dnd-file-upload

Comment: @Thanks Dee. I've got my answer.