# Is it possible to upload a file by dragging a file from the desktop to the browser

Tags: jquery

The idea is you drag a icon(of a specific file) from desktop and release on a particular location at the website??? Is it possible to implement (By jquery?)

Comment: It's possible. Just look at imgur.com. Might want amend the question to ask specifically.

Comment: Thanks. specifically.. , alright
1.Which language can do this trick??
2.IS that support for different browsers?

Comment: google has also implemented it see the image search http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663741/is-there-a-good-jquery-drag-and-drop-file-upload-plugin

Comment: I don't think it is supported in all web browsers, so I would be tempted to offer both variations. Especially portable browsers

Comment: Is it difficult to modify those plugin??? OR perharps diy a similiar one?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use [PlUpload](http://www.plupload.com/) for doing this task. Because this component based on a lot of plug-in or feature depend on what is plug-in that available in current browser. But it still has some limitation on drag-drop feature.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer: **Yes**, you can, but it is no simple task. Don't expect a one liner *without a plugin.*

For more information, how hard is it to google it? [Here](http://www.google.co.nz/#hl=en&cp=26&gs_id=2t&xhr=t&q=drag+and+drop+file+upload+jquery&pf=p&sclient=psy&biw=1280&bih=929&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=drag+and+drop+file+upload+&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=50631c5c2793d042)

A good demo: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload
A plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/drag-drop-upload
Another plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/drag-and-drop-upload
*Another* good plugin: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
**And look at this question**: [Is there a good jQuery Drag-and-drop file upload plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663741/is-there-a-good-jquery-drag-and-drop-file-upload-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it to use a plugin there are many out there for instance

http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Valum's Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)...it works great, and has the drag to upload capabilities you are looking for.

To better answer the question you asked in the comment of this answer, if you change that class to the following, boom, you have a full page drop area...

```
.qq-upload-drop-area {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 70px;
z-index: 2;
background: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5);
text-align: center;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah i have seen the website, really great but , how can the screen go blur and  a UPLOAD LOGO at the center just like what imgur does?

Comment: It is fully customizable...for instance you could make the class .qq-upload-drop-area expand the entire screen instead of just the area that it shows by default.