# How to program uploading image by using drag and drop technic

Tags: php, image, drag-and-drop

use PHP and MySQL. Want my website to have the feature of image uploading by drag image from folder from user's computer to some container on the web like div tag or something else. help me please.

Comment: Have you researched any methods?

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663741/is-there-a-good-jquery-drag-and-drop-file-upload-plugin

Comment: i found one technic by Jquery drag and drop but not sure can drag from folder or not.

Comment: uh by the way, Jquery is free or not? I really dont' know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag & Drop Functionality can be achieved using HTML & JavaScript

HTML5 have a native support for Drag and Drop

[HTML5 Drag & Drop Example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)