# Upload drag&dropped file with HTML5/jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, html

After playing with `HTML5` I'm still not able to solve this simple task:

Upload the content and MIME type of a drag&dropped text/image to the browser onto server (possibly with jQuery). So, I want to drop the file in the browser windows and let it go to the server (MVC, C#).

Please, how to achieve that? Using `FileReader` it's supposed to be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this jQuery plugins:
http://www.plupload.com/
http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

And try to use search :)
[Is there a good jQuery Drag-and-drop file upload plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663741/is-there-a-good-jquery-drag-and-drop-file-upload-plugin)