# Drag n Drop Feature - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I have a requirment to allow Drag and Drop with out using HTML5.  This drag and drop feature will allow a file to be dragged from the users desktop to a surface on a browser in my ASP.NET application.

I am having very little luck finding any thing even third party applications that will work and do this.

Comment: As far as I know, this is strictly a new feature in HTML5 , if you are going to have clients install a 3rd party application on their computer for drag and drop, why not just have them install a browser that supports that feature instead?

Comment: Why can't you use new HTML 5 features and provide an alternative for older browsers?

Comment: What about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663741/is-there-a-good-jquery-drag-and-drop-file-upload-plugin that points to this answer http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @Scott - That isn't compatible without HTML5. I tried on IE8 with no success. Worked very nice in chrome though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options:
These do not work in IE.

http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/drag-and-drop-upload

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

http://www.element-it.com/multiple-file-upload/silverlight-image-uploader.aspx (Silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without a browser/OS plugin

Comment: Looking for that kind of plugin